# pusher-java-client eventQueue inside onCreate

Tags: android, pusher

Hi im using pusher for notifications, after some test i keep having troubles, now i have this message when i intent to load a task.

```
02-08 13:43:56.751 20712-21208/package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pusher-java-client eventQueue
                                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pusher.client.connection.websocket.WebSocketClientWrapper
                                                                           at com.pusher.client.util.Factory.newWebSocketClientWrapper(Factory.java:67)
                                                                           at com.pusher.client.connection.websocket.WebSocketConnection$1.run(WebSocketConnection.java:63)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

this is how i call pusher connection in onCreate

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Create a new Pusher instance
            Pusher pusher = new Pusher("KEY");

            pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                    System.out.println("State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() +
                            " from " + change.getPreviousState());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("There was a problem connecting!");
                }
            }, ConnectionState.ALL);

            Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");

            channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
                    System.out.println("Received event with data: " + data);
                }
            });

            pusher.disconnect();

            pusher.connect();
            logger.info("Hubo un problema al conectarse");

        }
    });
```

Im stuck here, i don´t know if im implementing in a bad way the Thread, some tips will be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this error is the 64K limit in android VM.
 
To fix it U should download this jar:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/pusher/pusher-java-client/1.2.1/pusher-java-client-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Add it and remove any existing java-client-* from your project dependency.
Also remove any com.google.gson from your gradle.build file.
Finally, enable multidex in your project:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
that worked for me.